# Delegated click event on anchors

Tags: javascript

I am trying to target anchor tags and trigger an ajax request. Using jQuery this is very easy:

```
$(document.body).on('click', "a", function (event) {
    'use strict';
    if ($(this).is('.a-btn')) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if ($(this).is('.no-sp')) {
        //
    } else {
        address = $(this).attr("href")
        event.preventDefault();
        App.Ajax.Page(address + '/');
    }
});
```

However using native javascript, I would imagine using `event.target` would do the trick.

But this does not work, because the event always targets whatever element is inside the anchor tag:

```
App.Ajax.Navigate = function () {
    'use strict';
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.currentTarget);
        if (e.target.tagName === 'a') {
            var element, link;
            element = e.target;
            link = element.href;

            if (App.HTML.hasClass(element, 'a-btn')) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else if (App.HTML.hasClass(element, 'no-sp')) {
                return;
            } else {
                e.preventDefault();
                App.Ajax.Page(link);
            }

        }
    }, true);

    window.onpopstate = function (event) {
        App.Page.type = event.state.type;
        App.Page.Replace(event.state.content, event.state.type, App.Empty, false);
    };
};
```

I want to use native javascript to do what jquery does in the first code snippet, is it possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest - 2 polifills here

```
event.target.closest("a")
```

Don't forget about polifill for most browsers.

---

```js
(function(e){ 
  if (!e.matches) {
    e.matches = e.mozMatchesSelector || e.msMatchesSelector || e.oMatchesSelector || e.webkitMatchesSelector;
  }

  if (!e.closest) {
    e.closest = function (css) { 
      for (var node = this; node; node = node.parentElement) { 
        if (node.matches(css)) {
          return node; 
        }
      }

      return null; 
    } 
  }
})(Element.prototype);
```

Comment: I don't want to use an experimental method that isn't supported in all browsers.

Comment: @epascarello, but you can use polifill for it. See 2 solutions by the link in the answer (updated, now it points English version of documentation).

Comment: @SebastianOlsen, then just copy polifill code to your own method.